# Windows Service stops sending request to api after an exception "Session has unexpectedly closed"

Tags: c#, exception, windows-services

I have a windows service working in background on a remote windows server. It somehow stops sending request to api address. It doesn't stop but to function again, it needs a restart. When I check the logs I encountered a line of exception at the end of the log file that says"Session has unexpectedly closed".
What can be the problem here?

When I googled this message I couldn't find anybody or any thread that exactly encountered with this message.

Comment: You're going to have to provide some more detail on what your service does.  Is it using RDP sessions?  Web sessions?  Other sessions?!

Comment: Does your service relay on user profile interaction? are there package drops or TCP RST? Do you have long lived connections to external resources that could time out? Hard to know with the info provided

Comment: Without any more information, we can't answer this. Are you using WinSCP? What is the entire stack trace? What is your code doing when this exception occurs?

Comment: Read [ask] and [edit] your question so it contains a [mre]. Don't tell about your code; show it.